# warning wp session

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, posts, wp-admin

my website is down and has this error
Warning: Private methods cannot be final as they are never overridden by other classes in /var/www/vhosts/katalytes.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-session-tokens.php on line 69
[image]

could you please help me to fix it?i also cant login to wordpress admin and i cant work if my site is down

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just updated from PHP 7 to PHP 8 but you're still using a really old version of WordPress. The obvious solution is to either update WordPress or downgrade PHP version.